# Como cambiar re direccionamiento por defecto de login_required en Django?

Tags: python, django

Estoy usando el decorador login_required para no permitir el ingreso sin autentificar pero quisiera que cuando se ingrese a un link sin loguearse me redireccione a una pagina en especifica y no a la que viene por defecto que es account/login
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/home/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas usando el decorador `login_required` en tus `urls` lo que debes hacer es definir las siguientes variables en tu `settings.py`:

[LOGIN_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-url)
[LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#logout-redirect-url)

`LOGIN_URL` por defecto tiene la ruta `/accounts/login/`, ahora, si lo que quieres es redirigir a otra url cuando se ingresa a una vista en específico (sin estar logueado), puedes usar el decorador `login_required` en tu vista y pasarle como argumento la ruta a la cual quieres redirigir, ejemplo:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required 

@login_required(login_url='/tu/url/')
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

espero te sirva :)